# ctl+c during do-release-upgrade, now don't know what to do

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I can't seem to figure this out.  I'm currently dealing with fragmented rem sleep too, so please bear with me as my brain is not working either.

I was running do-release-upgrade via ssh but accidentally pressed ctl+c while I was confirming whether or not the installer should replace my files with the ones from the package.  Whole screen just starts bugging out.

Eventually I get back to the shell, but after restoring the sources.list.distUpgrade backup to the sources.list file, and then running apt update and do-release-upgrade, it just comes up as saying that there is not upgrade available, and idk what to do.

Comment: Where was the process up to during the `do-release-upgrade` when you cancelled it via ^C ??   If it was still downloading & hadn't started any installs; your system is the older release; if it started it's first install your system is no longer the initial/older release & you cannot ^C abandon the *release-ugprade* without consequences.. You did not want to touch/restore anything before working out where exactly it was at abort time - as that determines where you go from there.  If you were being asked questions about replace... it had already started installing newer packages I bet.

Comment: Yeah it had already started asking whether or not to replace certain configuration files.  I'm not sure I could give any details beyond that though, as I'm still a noob regarding linux and computers in general.

Comment: Is this likely going to be a clean reinstall then, or can I still salvage my install?  As far as I'm aware, things are still working.  It's a raspberry pi that I'm using to primarily run qbittorrent-nox, pi-hole, and plex, and as far as I'm aware, everything's still working.

Comment: I've just seen that on the ssh connection prompt, it's saying that the new release '20.04.1 LTS' is available, and to run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it, but when I run that it says there is no development version of an LTS available.  It also says a restart is required, but I'm skeptical as to whether rebooting right now is a good idea as there will probably be problems with boot?

Comment: If your system installed the first package; it is no longer the old release you're using, but the newer release you were *release-upgrading* to ... thus if you were going from 20.04 to 22.04; part of your system is now 22.04, parts still likely if it didn't complete if not all had completed install when you ^C...  Restore your sources to what they were when you hit ^C, then `sudo apt update` , then `sudo apt full-upgrade` and let it complete the upgrade.... Where you ^C in the process is what I see as critical... if it had installed first package... continue with `full-upgrade`

Comment: Sorry for this question, but how do I restore my sources?  Is this the sources.list file in /etc/apt/ ?  And by restore my sources, do you mean to rename 'sources.list.distUpgrade' to 'sources.list' ?

Comment: By restoring your sources I mean reversing anything you did to them... the sources should **not** have been touched IF any install of package had started..  You need to reverse anything you did & put them back to the state they were in when you hit ^C ... ie. if you edited them; reverse your edits.. etc

Comment: I didn't edit them knowingly.  By edit them do you mean the installers replacing the files with the package ones?  I'm sorry I'm so uneducated with these matters, I don't really know what you're saying :/

Comment: You mean the sources.list file, or are there 'source' files for each package?

Comment: You mention "*after restoring the sources.list.distUpgrade backup to the sources.list file*" thus it sounds like you changed them to me... any changes you made should be undone.

Answer (score 1):

Once a release-upgrade has begun *installing* packages, your system is most vulnerable.

Whether your system is salvageable or not depends upon the exact package install that was occurring when interrupted. Some systems can be recovered easily, others are destroyed.

Run `sudo apt full-upgrade` to *try* to resume the release-upgrade. It might work, it might not. If it fails, then back up your data and reinstall Ubuntu.

If `full-upgrade` works without ANY errors, then your system is likely (not certainly) going to be okay.

- If you encounter ANY errors while trying to fix a botched release-upgrade, our advice is likely to be "Not worth the effort to troubleshoot: Reinstall". There are simply too many things that could be wrong, and many troubleshooting techniques cannot be trusted to give reliable answers because *your system is starting from an inconsistent state*. It's untangling a knot while blindfolded...and while a dozen laughing children simultaneously are working to make the knot worse.

The next commands to complete the release-upgrade are are `sudo apt autoremove`, then `sudo apt autoclean`, then `sudo snap refresh`. Stop if you encounter errors. Do not skip steps.

- Pro Tip: Always be prepared with a LiveUSB. Use it to back up your data in an emergency.